# Change the background color of a screen with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I navigate to a view with stack navigator. The new screen has a different background color `#E9E9EF`, I do not know where it comes from. I figured out that this color is set in react-navigation/lib/views/CardStack/Card.js.
I tried to change the view background color but it didn't worked

```
return (
  <View style={{backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'}}>
  </View>
)
```

I also tried to change the card style with this code in StackNavigator and the color didn't changed

```
Other: {
    screen: AppOtherContainer,
    cardStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'},
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: navigation.state.params.title
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tintColor` to your navigation options

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: navigation.state.params.title,
    header: navigation => ({
      titleStyle: {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      },
      tintColor: '#F5FCFF'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the header color, then try this.

```
static navigationOptions = {
     title: navigation.state.params.title,
     headerStyle: {backgroundColor:"red"}}
```

If you want to change the background color of the screen that is rendered then set

`<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex:1}}> </View>`

Comment: I want to change the whole screen color